# Akka ZeroMQExtension Req socket sending procedure

Tags: scala, akka, zeromq

I have a tiny Rep server that I'm able to successfully send a message to using the below code:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.zeromq._
import org.zeromq.ZMQ
import akka.util.ByteString

class Sender extends Actor {

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    val context = ZMQ.context(1)
    val socket = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ)
    socket.connect ("tcp://127.0.0.1:1234")
    socket.send("test".getBytes(), 0)
    println("Sent!")
    //val reqSocket =     ZeroMQExtension(context.system).newReqSocket(
    //                        Array(Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:1234")))
    //reqSocket ! ZMQMessage(ByteString("test"))
  }

  def receive : Receive = {
    case _ =>
  }
}
```

However, if I use the commented out part instead (and comment out everything else in the def), then the server is unable to detect any message. Am I supposed to use some other sort of procedure to send the message when using `ZeroMQExtension`? I'm using ZeroMQ version 2.2.0.

For reference, here is the server code:

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.zeromq._

class ReplyActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case _ =>
      println("Received something!")
  }
}

object Replyer extends App {
   val system = ActorSystem("zmq")
   val serverSocket = ZeroMQExtension(system).newRepSocket(
   Array(Bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:1234"),
         Listener(system.actorOf(Props[ReplyActor]))))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server, switch the case _ => code to the following:

case x => println("msg is: " + x)

You will then find that your ReplyActor and your Sender end up getting a 'Connecting' message. I have found that you can't send/receive anything until you get this 'Connecting' message. It just means that you are actually connected. Once you get that, then you can start sending / receiving messages.

Comment: All I get is `msg is: ZMQMessage(Vector(ByteString(116, 101, 115, 116)))` which should be the bytes for "test". If I change the client code to the presently commented code, I get nothing.

Comment: Yep. It takes some time to setup the socket in the first of your commented out lines. It is an asynchronous call. If you then send the 'test' string in your second line that is commented out, the socket is likely not ready yet :(

Comment: At least that is what I am seeming to find :(

Comment: Ah, yes, if I `sleep` a little after having set up the socket it's able to send the message through (I don't see any 'connecting' messages though). Is there some more proper way of doing it without `Thread.sleep`? Thanks for the help, I wish I could upvote you but I don't have enough rep yet. :(

Comment: I am not sure if there is a better way. I am just trying to get ZMQ working myself and had stumbled across the same issue. hehe. No worries about the up vote.  I would be interested if you find a 'better' way to go about this without having to sleep. I have yet to find any good examples/information about it :(